# WAMP apache server : problem running php files

Tags: apache-http-server

I have installed WAMP 2 and am using firefox 3.6. I have saved my php file test.php in 
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\htdocs
and I now open http://localhost/test.php in my firefox browser but I get a file not found error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your files in the www directory. Right click on the WAMMP icon on the taskbar > Click on www directory to launch the directory and place your php files there.

Also don't forget to start all services

[image: WAMMP]

Alternatively you can also use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). In XAMPP you have to place the files directly in XAMPP > htdocs folder.

XAMPP also has a plugin for TOMCAT so that you can test java apps locally.